# Enum Flags Negative Value

Tags: c#

Got a *negative* number (`-2147483392`)

I don't understand *why* It (correctly) casts to a flags `enum`.

Given

```
[Flags]
public enum ReasonEnum
{
    REASON1 = 1 << 0,
    REASON2 = 1 << 1,
    REASON3 = 1 << 2,
    //etc more flags
    //But the ones that matter for this are
    REASON9 =  1 << 8,
    REASON17 = 1 << 31  
}
```

why does the following correctly report `REASON9` and `REASON17` based off a *negative number*?

```
var reason = -2147483392;
ReasonEnum strReason = (ReasonEnum)reason;
Console.WriteLine(strReason);
```

.NET Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aDLx0j)

I say *correctly*, as this was an event reason property being fired from a COM component, and when cast as the `enum` value, it was *correct* in the values it casts to (as per that event). The flags enum was as per the SDK documentation for the COM object. The COM object is third party and I have no control over the number, based off the interface it will always be supplied as an INT

Comment: the topmost bit (`31-th`) set means *negative number*, see *two's complement*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Why don't you specify the enum type rather than let the compiler do it for you and do it wrong.

Comment: @jdweng The compiler isn't doing anything wrong.

Comment: Consider `public enum ReasonEnum : long {}` if this makes you nervous.  You probably will have to anyway sooner or later since you can't add yet another member.

Comment: Just to be clear, the number (-2147483392) I am given is from the (third party) COM component, so I have no control over at all. All I am given is a int property with the reason, and an SDK that says check this reason against a bit mask values. Not sure having the enum as a long on my side is going to help anything, arguably it will mean a value of 2147483904 will mean the same thing but if the interface is always giving me an int.....

Comment: I don't remember (and I'm not near a compiler), but can the integral type associated with an `enum` be a `uint`? If so, that might be a simple/clear solution

Comment: I didn't say the compile was doing anything wrong, just not what the OP expected.  Try public enum ReasonEnum : UInt32

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The topmost bit set (*31-th* in your case of `Int32`) means *negative number* (see [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for details):

```
  int reason = -2147483392;

  string bits = Convert.ToString(reason, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');

  Console.Write(bits);
```

Outcome:

```
  10000000000000000000000100000000
  ^                      ^
  |                      8-th
  31-th
```

And so you have

```
  -2147483392 == (1 << 31) | (1 << 8) == REASON17 | REASON9
```

Comment: So just to be clear this is simply a product turning on the left most bit on an `INT`, which is the negative bit, which is equivalent to `int.MinValue` (i.e. just the negative flag turned on so the twos compliment will be all other bits turned on `int.MaxValue`), and this is purely because the default datatype of an `enum` is `INT`

Comment: @OJay: you are quite right; I'd rather not put 31-th bit as a "negative" bit (`int32.MinValue == 1000...0b` when `-1 == 111...1b`); if you set 31-th bit to `1` in `X`; you'll get some *negative* value, but not `-X`

Comment: OK cool, minor assumption in terminology aside, I think I am clear. yeah calling it the 'negative bit' may be a bit (pun intented) mislading, perhaps the twos compliment bit? I'm not sure what makes sense to be honest, negative bit flag which means twos compliment is run.....bit of a mouthful but more correct?

Comment: @OJay: To be exact in terms, we have negative (or *sign*) bit in floating point values, like `double` and `float` (and that's why unlike `Int32` we can distinguish negative and positive zeroes). I don't know any special name of 31-th bit (except topmost, leftmost ect.) in case of `Int32`